# Program crashes when segueing back and dispatch queue has animation method

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiscrollview, grand-central-dispatch, segue

Ok so i have a uitableview and when an item is selected it segues to a new view controller to show an image (inside of a uiscrollview).  The image begins downloading in a dispatch_queue from prepareforsegue.  To be clear I am doing all UI updates in the main queue.  The problem is that if i hit the back button quick enough then my program crashes with an exc_bad_address.  I think the problem has to deal with zoomToRect animated:YES because when i set animated to NO i cant get it to crash.  Plus the call stack below deals with animation.  What is the best way to go about fixing this and is there a better way to get what i need done?

Also when debugging the problem print 'Block completed' and then crashes shortly after.

[stack trace](http://i49.tinypic.com/23qxc0m.jpg)

Here is the method called. It is called in a setter of the destination controller in prepareForSegue.

```
-(void) updateDisplay {
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("Load Flickr Photo", NULL);

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        UIImage *image = [FlickrFetcher imageForPhoto:self.currentPhoto format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
            self.imageView.image = image;
            self.title = [FlickrFetcher titleForPhoto:self.currentPhoto];    
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
            self.imageView.transform = transform;

            self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);

            self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
            self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = .2;
            self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1;
            self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.bounds.size;

            //i think problem is here
            [self.scrollView zoomToRect:self.imageView.frame animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"Block completed");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a potential problem could be that while your block retains your `self` the view controller while its active in queue...

If you send `-zoomToRect:animated:NO`, the block will still be active and blocking on the call which ensures that all the objects are still valid in memory.

If you send `-zoomToRect:animated:YES`, the block will exit potentially generating a race condition where your view controller would be released since storyboards will also release your view controller when you go back in a segue leaving it with an effective retain count of zero.